# string comparison in Chrome changing mid-function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am getting a totally bizarre issue in Chrome v. 33 that looks as if the string comparison operator is broken.  It only occurs with the developer tools closed.  I have the following function:

```
function TabSelected(data) {
  var tab, was_design;
  this.data = data;
  tab = this.data.tab;
  was_design = tab === 'design';
  if (this.data.tab === 'design') {
    this.tab = 1;
  } else {
    this.tab = 2;
    console.log('was_design');
    console.log(was_design);
    console.log('is_design');
    console.log(tab === 'design');
  }
}
```

Which I call like so:

```
new TabSelected({
    tab: 'design'
  });
```

I have a setInterval running that runs this code every 50 ms.  Most of the time, the `if` statement picks the first code path, so nothing gets logged to the console.  However, after about ~8 seconds, it goes down the `else` code path.  When I open the developer tools afterwards (since the bug doesn't happen when they're closed), I see the following log output:

```
was_design (index):96624
false (index):96625
is_design (index):96626
true (index):96627
```

I am... confused by this.  I've also tried logging the contents of `tab`, which is in fact 'design', and logging `this`, which is a new TabSelected instance.

Am I losing my mind?  Is Chrome losing it's mind?

UPDATE: I was able to reproduce it in a simplified setting: http://jsfiddle.net/WBpLG/24/.  I'm pretty sure this is a bug with Chrome and I've filed an issue, see answer below.

Comment: Can you provide a live example reproducing the issue?

Comment: Don't log the contents of `tab`. Log the contents of the `(this.)data.tab` property! Since you only got a reference to the `data` object, anything could change this. What other code might have access to that object?

Comment: @Jonathan: go to ec2-54-80-155-147.compute-1.amazonaws.com/learn and count to five slowly.  If you figure this out I'm buying you a beer...

Comment: @Bergi -- I changed it to eliminate the `tab` variable and just use `this.data.tab`... no effect.  Anyway, no other code should be able to touch this since javascript is single-threaded and the error happens over the course of a single function call.

Comment: @josh:  You said something of `setInterval` so I thought in between something could happen… but you're right, it seems to happen during the execution of the constructor.

Comment: I saw the page you mentioned but seems to me like a DOM redraw issue, as if you were getting the element while redrawn or similar. Could it be?

Comment: +1, I can confirm the issue with Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Make this change and the problem should go away:

`if (this.data.tab === 'design') {`

to

`if (String(this.data.tab) === 'design') {`

However, I can confirm that `typeof this.data.tab === 'string'` both before the `if` clause and during the `else`, so I think this is only a partial answer at best.

Alternatively, I can also clear the problem by adjusting `NewElementButtonSectionOpened.prototype.previous_requirement` on line 59440:

```
// Create a single instance of the requirement and store it in the closure.
var cachedReq = new TabSelected({ tab: 'design' });

// Now just return that one instance over and over again.
NewElementButtonSectionOpened.prototype.previous_requirement = function() {
  // deleted line: return new TabSelected({ tab: 'design' });
  return cachedReq;
};
```

While both of these solutions fix the problem on my machine, it is not clear to me *why* this works.

I am afraid to mention it, but at one point, I was also able to prevent the error from happening by adding a `throw new Error("...");` line in your `else` block.  In other words, changing something in the `else` block altered the behavior of the `if` check.  My only clue here is that the *length of the error message mattered*.  For a while there, I could clear the error or cause the error consistently by altering the length of an error message that would never be thrown.  This is so bizarre that I must surely have been mistaken, and indeed, I can no longer replicate it.

However, this *is* an *extremely* large JavaScript file.  Maybe there is something to that.  Maybe it is just a ghost story.  This problem is certainly quite creepy enough without it, but just in case somebody else sees something similar... You aren't alone.

Comment: Your second workaround is what I ended up doing.  I also filed a bug with Chromium (I was able to reproduce this in a much simpler jsFiddle, see the answer I just added...)  Thanks for confirming that I'm not crazy :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a simple reproduction case, so I've filed a [bug with Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=string%20comparison&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&id=346587&thanks=346587&ts=1393299225).

The necessary conditions seem to be: a setInterval or repeating setTimeout, an expensive computation in the body of the interval, a call to a new Object passing data that contains a string, and a string comparison.